# How to sort a complex list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I'm stuck this question for a while.  I have a nested list, its structure looks like

```
Volume1
    Chapter4
    Chapter3
        Section3-6
        Section3-1
Volume2...
...
```

What I want is to create a sort function to sort volume, chapter, and section.

So, the result may be like

```
Volume1
    Chapter1
        Section1-1
....
```

So I got a complex html, here is the [whole html](https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/f1a17897737c4d569cecf64299bdeeb1).
I'm not sure how to swap this complex `div`
I've tried to get element and put them into an array.

```
var toSort = document.getElementById('volume5015').children;
toSort = Array.prototype.slice.call(toSort, 0);
```

Comment: what does 'volume<%=volume[0]%>' mean? isn't this jsp syntax?

Comment: Why not just going recursively and sort the items like you would normally do?

Comment: You might have better luck sorting the underlying data structure instead of html.

Comment: Sorry, it's `('volume5015')`. I forgot to change the rails syntax.

Comment: Think the [sortChildren plugin](https://github.com/JakeCigar/jQuery.sortChildren) (or similar) could do the job for you.

Comment: @Michal Jarnot , I did display this html  recursively, but now I may add new item or delete item, then click sort button without any refresh.

Comment: @georg But it seems need to call ajax, I don't want user call ajax, it may slow down server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle for you.

In my code I am trimming the whitespaces of the text so the don't get compared but you don't actually have to if you don't want.

```
var $items = $("#to-sort").children();
var $resultList = $("#list2");

sortMarkup($items, $resultList);

function sortMarkup($elements, $output) {
  $elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    var contentA = getPureText(a).trim();
    var contentB = getPureText(b).trim();
    var okay = contentA.toUpperCase().localeCompare(contentB.toUpperCase());

    if( $(a).children().length > 0 )
        sortMarkup( $(a).children(), $(a) );

    if( $(b).children().length > 0 )
        sortMarkup( $(b).children(), $(b) );

    console.log("sorting ["+contentA+"] and ["+contentB+"] returned "+okay);
    return okay;
  });

  $output.append($elements);
}

function getPureText(elem) {
    return $(elem).contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3; 
    })[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Also, I am using an output list, another thing that is not required. Feel free to modify to your needs!

**fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/vincelord/sn42argq/

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction, I thought it's too hard to get pure text for every tag, I think I should consider sorting origin data and then append new data in right position.